# Yii2 rest API get post with user

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am creating REST API in `YII2`. I am getting all post data by calling get API

```
/post/
/post/1/
```

But I want to get user also who post that particular post.

for example I want data in below format

```
{
      "id":"1",
      "title":"kapil",
      "content" : "test",
      "user" : {
         "username":"admin",
         "first_name":"kapil",
         "last_name":"sharma",
          //blah blah
      }

}
```

But response is

```
{
          "id":"1",
          "title":"kapil",
          "content" : "test",
}
```

I used [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) tutorial for creating API.

Comment: where is your code??

Comment: I just create controller and rest of the work is done by default Yii2 REST API format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say in your post method you have the `getIdUser()` relation:

```
public function getIdUser() {
  return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

In that model, you should make use of the `extraFields()` method, as follows:

```
public function extraFields() {
  return [
    'user' => 'idUser' // or the name you hasOne relation with user has
  ];
}
```

Then, you call your REST API with the `expand` parameter, specifying there which `extraField` details you'd like to include, in your case:

http://example.com/post/view?id=1&expand=user

Comment: How can i create a relation. I am new in Yii